# Register Salesforce application in Azure Active Directory

Tags: rest-api, integration, activedirectory, azure

I have a VF page that is supposed to display a report from Power BI. When i try registering the Web App(SalesForce in this case) i get the following error

```
ERROR: Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I am giving the following values for the paramaters:

```
App Name:PowerBI
App Type:Server side Web App
Redirect URL:https://aneeshlogic-dev-ed--c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/PowerBI_Report
Home Page URL: https://aneeshlogic-dev-ed.lightning.force.com
```

I am using a developer account with a domain name (evident from the URL). "PowerBI_Report" is the VF page which is supposed to display the report. What wrong am i doing here?

Comment: This question looks dangerously off-topic. But, however, I want to ask a follow up question. Did you authenticate into SFDC? if so, does the user you authenticated as have permissions to that page?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I am the user and i have permissions to that page. However, when i specify the Redirect URL i do not know how to provide my credentials as query parameters.